# How to compare two speech recognition softwares?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I am working on building speech recognition software for my company.

In the meantime however, we will purchase some off-the-shelf commercial speech recognizers until the in-house one is ready. My question:
1. How are speech recognizers evaluated?
2. Are there any standardized tests available that can be used to test speech recognizers and determine the better one of the two?

Answer (score 1):

NIST has a web page that provides a good detailed discussion of how to score ASR software.

http://www.isip.piconepress.com/projects/speech/software/tutorials/production/fundamentals/v1.0/section_04/s04_03_p01.html